# What is the origin of the usage of the word "rook" as it refers to the chess piece?

Tags: etymology

And when did it start being used that way?  Before or after the bird meaning of "rook"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rook)

> "chess piece," c.1300, from O.Fr. roc,
>   from Arabic rukhkh, from Pers. rukh,
>   of unknown meaning, perhaps somehow
>   related to the Indian name for the
>   piece, rut, from Hindi rath "chariot."

According to the OED, the word rook meaning the bird was first used circa 725.

So it seems that the two words have different origins.

Comment: *rukh* is normally assumed to refer to a roc (as in Sinbad).  Enough to confuse the issue, at least.

Answer (score 4):

The rook is definitely named from the Persian word rukh meaning war-chariot as the corresponding piece in Oriental games is also called a chariot. However as the game came to Europe the word got confused with the Italian word rocca meaning a tower. That's why it's represented as a fortified tower and referred to informally as a castle. Nothing to do with the bird.

Comment: Interesting theory.  Citation?

Comment: rocca is on the Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_%28chess%29 although I'm fairly sure this theory is in the Oxford Companion to Chess (Hooper & Whyld) but I don't have my copy within reach.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case (when the word is used to refer to a chess piece), the origin of the word is Middle English, from Old French *rock*, based on Arabic *ruḵḵ*.
In the second case, the origin of the word is from Old English *hrōc*.

The word has been first used to refer to the bird, but the two words have different origins.